# Compiling node.js on Cygwin

Tags: build, installation, cygwin, compilation, node.js

I'm trying to build node.js on my Windows XP box (Yes, it IS painful, thanks.) using Cygwin following Ryans instructions [here](http://wiki.github.com/ry/node/building-node-on-windowscygwin).

Sadly calling "./configure" from the node source directory barfs up this:

```
$ ./configure
/home/LWE/sources/node.js/wscript: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/LWE/sources/node.js/tools/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 274, in load_module
    exec(compile(code, file_path, 'exec'), module.__dict__)
  File "/home/LWE/sources/node.js/wscript", line 12, in <module>
    import js2c
  File "/home/LWE/sources/node.js/tools/js2c.py", line 35, in <module>
    import jsmin
  File "/home/LWE/sources/node.js/tools/jsmin.py", line 1
    ../deps/v8/tools/jsmin.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm absolutely not into Python so I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Am I missing some dependency or what?

I'd expect that there is some simple little configuration switch that I have to turn, to make this work. I just don't know where/what/why/...

I compiled node.js on my Mac before from the very same sources and that worked like a charm. And I also can't imagine that the build script from the node repository itself is broken.

PS: It's a totally fresh and up to date Cygwin installation with Python 2.6.5.

Comment: Update: I got the build script running but don't ask me how. After messing around with some of the python scripts, I basically reverted everything to its original state and then the error was gone ... However the build still fails after quite a while of compiling. I'm giving up on this. Node is more fun on my Mac anyway ...

Answer (score 3):

I also had a problem getting nodejs to compile using cygwin - also a Python issue. I eventually found a reference to having to rebase the cygwin DLL links to make everything work. Of course I couldn't find my original source for help. But I remembered enough to find similar help.

So from http://avalanche123.tumblr.com/post/855374337/nodejs-mongodb-tinyurl

I remembered that you can stop all cygwin processes, run ash (a minimal shell) that is typically found at C:\cygwin\bin\ash.exe and then, in this shell, run "/usr/bin/rebaseall"

Once I had run the rebaseall command I could, using the normal cygwin shell, successfully run the ./configure script for the nodejs source and proceed to "make" and "make install" nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but for anyone referencing this page: `jsmin.py` is a symbolic link. If you are using Git from msysGit in Cygwin, symbolic links will not be created properly. The Git client that comes with Cygwin deals with these pretty decently most of the time, however every now and then it barfs. If you bring up `jsmin.py` in an editor, you will see it actually contains the path to the file it is supposed to be linking to. To fix this and move on to compiling:

```
# from the node.js source directory, run:
% cd tools
% ln -fs `cat jsmin.py`
```

This will recreate the symlink pointing to the proper location. From here, re-run `./configure` and you are all set.

A full set of build instructions is available at [Github](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29).

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems using Ryan's current instructions -- until I tried install ing NPM as well, and then I got no output. If you are using cygwin and installing node.js, be sure to use the "works" tag when you git the file, instead of a specific version number. Otherwise, no output/non working npm.

Now to figure out getting mongo setup properly...